# How to prevent code duplication in Dart functions?

Tags: dart

**Minimal reproducible code:**

```dart
bool _flag = true;
void main() {
  if (_flag) {
    apiFunction(a: 1, b: true, c: 'c');
  } else {
    apiFunction(a: 1, b: true);
  }
}

// Some function that I can neither change nor read its default values. 
void apiFunction({
  int a = 0,
  bool b = false,
  String c = '',
}) {...}
```

As you can see based on `flag`, I need to pass `c: 'c'`, and I'm currently duplicating `apiFunction(a: 1, b: true)` part. Is there any better way to write this?

Note: Please don't write this answer, because the default value is not given.

```dart
apiFunction(a: 1, b: true, c: _flag ? 'c' : '');
```

---

**Real world scenario (optional)**

For those who want to see this example in real world. When using [`cloud_firestore_odm`](https://pub.dev/packages/cloud_firestore_odm), the generated abstract method `update()` accepts non-nullable value (if the non nullable type was used for a field) and the method looks like this:

```dart
Future<void> update({
  int a,
  bool b,
  String c,
  // other fields ...
});
```

Its implementation looks like:

```dart
Future<void> update({
  Object? a = _sentinel,
  Object? b = _sentinel,
  Object? c = _sentinel,
  // other fields ...
})
```

Comment: There's no way to treat an argument as omitted without actually omitting it, so there's no good way to unify those function calls.  There are a number of GitHub issues about this sort of thing (for example: https://github.com/dart-lang/language/issues/1512, https://github.com/dart-lang/language/issues/1639, https://github.com/dart-lang/language/issues/577).

Comment: @jamesdlin Thanks, I was looking for an authentic comment/answer and now I'm a bit relaxed to see there's no good way.